# Launch android app with emergency dialer

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-intent, android-service

I'm developing an app and i want to launch it from the emergency dialer (the one you can access without unlocking the phone). When I call "*#*#123#*#*" it says that is not an emergency number so it can't be called. How could i make it?

I've already done a test with the regular dialer and it works fine.
I think about 2 things: making it assumed like an emergency nubmer (how?) or make "*#*#123#*#*" a special android code (as "*#06#" that give the IMEI number) and make it work under the emergency dialer (*#06# doesn't)

I know the question maybe a duplicate but have looked for hours and didn't find the answers. if so, may you give me the link?

Thanks a lot for your help, i'm so stuck at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

I think that emergency numbers are hardcoded in the system, so you cannot easily add your number in that list.

Comment: hum...Do you think we can make work android special code for emergency dialer and allow my code to be one of them or is it the same kind of thing?
Or maybe is there a way to bypass the recognition of the emergency number? I don't really want to make a call, I just want to make it recognized by my app to launch...I've tried to put a "1000" priority in my intent but no result...

Comment: I've read about root applications that can add numbers. But I've never tried them. You can try to search them if you have a rooted phone. Other possibility is to change android platform code )